# having problem with positioning the tkinter widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The position of Text widget is at the center-left in this code. I want it to be just below the Label widget at left side. I tried to define position by pady argument but it is not working. How can I change position of Text widget.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font

root = Tk()
root.title("Project")
root.geometry('700x400')

name = Label(root,text="Project")
name.configure(font=('Arial',20),fg='Blue',bg='yellow')
name.pack()

symbol_input = Text(root)
symbol_input.config(height=1,width=10)
symbol_input.pack(padx=5,side='left')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the `grid` system instead of `pack`? You can get more accurate results like that.

Comment: Just use place instead of pack:    name = Label(root,text="Project").place(x=10, y=45)    where "x" is the horizontal alignment...

Comment: `place` is rarely the best solution. It has its uses, but it requires more work to get a responsive GUI than either `grid` or `pack`.

Comment: Try changing `symbol_input.pack(padx=5,side='left')` to `symbol_input.pack()`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: grid() and pack(). I personally prefer the grid since it's more convenient for me with positioning and placing things on the frames. Whatever you choose though, be sure to maintain the same throughout your code since Tkinter wouldn't allow otherwise.

```
name = Label(root, text="Project", font=('Arial',20), fg='Blue, bg='yellow')
name.grid(sticky=N + E + W + S)
name.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=100)
name.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=100)
name.place(relx=0.28, rely=0.3)
```

The place() method allows you to place the label widget at any specific coordinate in your root. I have used relx (relative x) and rely (relative y) which tell where the widget should be relative to the root it's going to be in.

**0 <= relx, rely <= 1**

I recommend using relx and rely rather than just x or y since it will allow your program to work on other devices which have different sizes of screen (or even window resizing) without any repositioning relative to other widgets in the root.